# Fullpage.js : Sections have higher height than content

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

I'm currently working on a single page website using Bootstrap and fullpagejs :

I've followed the required HTML structure, but each sections of my website have got a huge height. So the sections don't fit with their content.

I noticed that if I add the fp-auto-height class, everything is ok. The content fits with the sections. But this is not the right way to do that.

I have no idea about what happens.

Here is my first section for example

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <!-- section 1 begin -->
    <div data-anchor="p1-a" class="section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="p1" class="row vertical-align">
                <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                         <h1 id="title-p1" class="reduce-space text-center">ANTHONY<span style="color: #E28509;">ROANI</span></h1>
                     </div>
                 </div> <!-- end row title intro -->
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="intro-text">
                           ...
                        </p>
                    </div><!-- end left intro -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="intro-text">
                           ...
                        </p>
                    </div> <!-- end right intro -->
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <i class="intro-text"> ...</i>
                        <p class="intro-text">- Luc Fayard </p>
                    </div><!-- end citation intro -->
                </div> <!-- end row content text intro -->
            </div> <!-- end colonnes + offset page 1 -->
        </div><!-- end bigrow page 1 -->
    </div>
</div> <!-- SECTION 1 END -->

[... other sections]
</div> <!-- end fullpage -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not forgetting to add the compulsory `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the very start of your document as detailed in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6602KMtq1Y).

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Demo
    </body>
</html>
```

Doctype is necessary in any website.